# MySQL Unique vs Primary key in relation to NULL values

Tags: mysql

I've noticed something whilst setting up a database and want to confirm with all you smart people!

I have a column that needs to accept `NULL` values, so I checked off the `NULL` checkbox in the easy to use PHPMyAdmin interface. easy.

When I add a unique index, everything is good. But, when I change that unique index to a Primary key (also unique), it removes the NULL option.

Why is this, and is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected. As told in [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#id1011362), PRIMARY KEY cannot accept NULL:

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined
>   as NOT NULL.